# Existence of stopping time in random interval

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we are given a filtered probability $(\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}\}_t,\mathbb{P})$ space fulfilling the "usual conditions" (.i.e. the filtration is right-continuous and complete). Let $\tau$ be a stopping time with respect to this space, let $a$ be a positive real number and assume $a<\tau$. Is it true that for any $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ there exists a stopping time $\sigma_{\epsilon,\delta}$ such that $\mathbb{P}\left(\sigma_{\epsilon,\delta}\in\left[\tau-a,\tau-a+\delta\right]\right)>1-\epsilon$.

Since the set $\left[\tau-a,\tau-a+\delta\right]$ is not optional I guess the optional section theorem will not yield anything useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you state in the post the original problem that you are trying to solve? As you mentioned too the $\tau-a$ is not a stopping time and so the reasonable choice $\sigma=\tau-a$ will not work https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160821/measurability-of-stopping-times.

Comment: No, there does not always exist such a stopping time.  For example, if $\mathbb{P}(\tau -a + \delta < 0) > 0$ for some $a, \delta > 0$.

Comment: @user6247850: Yes of course, I forgot to mention that we will assume $a<\tau$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no such stopping time exists in general.  Let $B$ be a Brownian motion, $\tau := \inf\{t > 2: B_t - B_2 \ge 1\} \wedge 3$, and $a = 2$.  Then if $\sigma$ is any stopping time, we will show there is an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}(\sigma \in [\tau - a, \tau - a + \delta])$.

First, we may assume WLOG that $\sigma \in [0,1 + \delta]$, so that $\mathcal{F}_\sigma \subset \mathcal{F}_2$ which is independent of $\tau$.  Then, because  $\{ \sigma \in [\tau - a, \tau - a + \delta]\} = \{\tau \in [\sigma + a - \delta, \sigma + a]\},$ by the independence lemma we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\sigma \in [\tau - a, \tau - a + \delta]) &= \mathbb{P}(\tau \in [\sigma + a - \delta, \sigma + a]) \\
&\le \sup_{b \in \mathbb{R}}  \mathbb{P}(\tau \in [b-\delta,b]).
\end{align*}

Since $\sup_{b \in \mathbb{R}}  \mathbb{P}(\tau \in [b-\delta,b]) < 1$ for all $\delta < 1$, one can therefore choose $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\sigma \in [\tau - a, \tau - a + \delta]) < 1-\varepsilon$ for all stopping times $\sigma$.